# Object from one view to another AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have array of objects, that I use to load a menu (based on user). This works fine.

```
<li class="sub-menu">
    <a href="javascript:;" >
        <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
        <span>Data Tables</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub" ng-repeat="data in myDataSets">
        <li><a ng-click="dataset(data)"  >{{ data.get('datasetName') }}</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Then my controller function dataset is structured like so

```
$scope.dataset = function(dataset) {
    $scope.DataPoints = dataset;
    $location.path('/datapoint');
}
```

I then want to load object (dataset) properties on the `/datapoint` view. But when i go to load thme on the `/datapoint` view I get that the DataPoints Array is blank, i.e. nothing has been saved.

I have a `console.log($scope.DataPoints)`  before `location.path` and it seems correct.

I declare `DataPoints`  as `var DataPoints=[];` which is similar to other functions that work fine.

EDIT: Code for `/datapoint`

```
<div class="row mt">
   <center><h3> Main Page  {{DataPoints.length }}</h3><center>
       <table class="table">
        <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Status</th>
           <th>Location</th>
       </tr>  
       <tr ng-repeat="test in DataPoints" >
           <td>{{ test.get('datapointName') }}</td>
           <td>{{ test.get('datapointNotes') }}</td>
       </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using routes and ngView? If not, and you're navigating to another URL, then you should be aware that scope data does not persist

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding with $scope bind it with $rootScope because you need Datapoints in different view. But remember to provide the dependency of `$rootscope` in the controller.

```
$rootscope.DataPoints=dataset;
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Can you provide the code of your controller at "/datapoint" point.I mean in your second view.

Comment: also note both pages have the same controller. but are different functions in the same controller.

Comment: Create different controller bcz u have two views :-)
Same controller will not help you...!!

Comment: but datapoint page needs to load data from 3 different arrays. I can only have one controller per page.(view)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are using ng-view and have two controllers, with differents scopes.

The point is: You need pass data from the first to the second controller... There is two options to do this:

1. Use $rootScope: You can store your property in the $rootScope ($rootScope is parent of all scopes), and access it from the second controller... This will solve your problem, but is not semantics...
2. Create a service (the docs are [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)). Services are singleton an lazily initiated, so you can create one and use to store the value in the first controller and read in the second.

I prefer the second option because you can: be more semantic, use DI, and implement the logic that runs over the value in the service rather than spread it.